# Power Automate Flow - send an email when a ticket in Azure DevOps is close to Completion Date

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

Trying to figure out how to create a flow on power automate that sends an email reminder to the assigned person on a ticket in Azure DevOps when there's only one day left on the completion date.  I've looked through nearly all the triggers and can't seem to find anything related to this. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What process are you using (Agile, Scrum, CMMI?) and what work item type are we talking about?

Normally I would say this should be possible by creating a query and using query results in your Power Automate flow.

In the personal or shared query use the following value in the date filter.
*In my example I used the Target Date column of a Feature Work Item in a Scrum process type of project btw.*

```
@StartOfDay('1d')
```

[image]

In the flow use a recurrence action and in the get query results action reuse that query you just created.

[image]

Add A Select below the Get Query Results to retrieve the fields you want to use. For the System.AssignedTo field I used an expression since that value is formatted as *DisplayName*

```
slice(split(item()?['System.AssignedTo'], '<')[1], 0, -1)
```

After that you can loop through the items of the Select.Per work item a reminder will be sent to the AssignedTo user.

[image]

Comment: we don't really use those processes, since we're in ecommerce. Theres only 5 work items we generally use, or at least within my purview: Epic, Feature, User Story, Task, and Bugs.

Comment: The example above should also work with those work item types. Try it out with your specific date field. 

Btw, when you create a project in Azure DevOps for the first time one of the mandatory fields is the selection of the Work Item process. So, I am pretty sure you are using some type of process. And from looking at your work item types available, I would say you are using the Agile process ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#create-a-project

Comment: Oooh I see, the way its structured is there's only one project, ecommerce. Within that we have all our tickets and issues. I don't deal with anything outside of ecommerce so I don't see any other projects (if we even have any) and I never create a new project either, only work items within the ecommerce project.

Ok so, the way you showed me helped me out a ton, I appreciate the info! However I don't know if what i'm trying to do is too specific. What I currently have is this as the query (still need to mess around to find the right one): https://i.imgur.com/zgQcPZG.png

Comment: and this as the flow:
https://i.imgur.com/12jhQCY.png

Comment: but Ideally, and this is where I think I might be too specific, what I want is to have a flow that sends an email reminder to the person who is assigned to the work item when it's 1 day out from reaching the completion date if the work item is not marked as completed or in production.

Comment: I will edit my answer and also add the e-mail part (which I forgot, tbh :P). Which fields do you want to use?

Comment: Currently just the completion date, which I believe is the field responsible for letting people know by what date the ticket needs to be completed.

Comment: oh and prob the "assigned to" field

Comment: Updated the answer. Included the title of the work item and the assigned to field, which we need for the To in the email.

Comment: ok damn, you just opened my eyes to how this works by a lot.

So, I can see based on what you did how it should work and the only problem I've got, I think, is for the query and how exactly to get it to show only work items that are 1 day from reaching their completion date. I messed around a bit by creating a test work item with the completion date being tomorrow:
https://i.imgur.com/H52UnMZ.png

and after messing around I finally got the query to show it by creating this:
https://i.imgur.com/4meFajV.png

I'm not sure if this is completely accurate but it seems to work?

Comment: If you only want the items which need to be completed tomorrow I would use the `Completion Date  = @StartOfDay('1d')` (equal) instead of the > (greater) operator.